# Why can´t I umask more permissions for others and group than owner

Tags: users, user-management

I have a "Guess" user on my ubuntu server 20.08.

I have decided to **umask** files which this user can create.
On his `.bashrc` i have wrote this:

```
umask 100
```

What mean :

[image]

So mean this :

> I want guess user can create files/dirs but only with **write and read** permissions. On this way, any other users can manage **guess user files** (*even execute it*).

But result is a bit different:

[image]

My goal is : `-rw-rwxrwx`.

Is not possible that `other` group has more privileges than `owners` ?

Answer (score 1):

The `x` permission is not normally given to files when they are created. You must set it up on a file manually with `chmod`.

Your `umask` setting will work properly if you create a **directory**, not a file. For example if you type `umask 100` followed by `mkdir somedir`, you get the following in the output:

```
drw-rwxrwx 2 raj raj 4096 mar 25 17:12 somedir
```